# Battery icon is missing from top wingpanel

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, battery

Just like what the title said.

I dual booted elementary OS Loki and realized that the battery icon has gone missing...

I've tried reinstalling everything, but it still does not show up.

I'm using a Surface Pro so is that possibly the case of the hardware not being supported?

Any advice/solution would be much appreciated.